# making a <div> 'snap' from one dimension to another

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

This seems like it should be easy with bootstrap/grid but I must be missing something. I have a container div with two column div's within it. When the screen size reaches a certain point, I want the container to change directly from the expanded size (780px in the example) to the compact size (just big enough for the viewport div, ~620px). I can get the internal div's to behave correctly, but the container div "slides" from the expanded size to the compact size. I want it be either one or the other width.

my html:

```
<div id="mc-container" class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
    <div id="mc-header">title bar</div>
    <div id='mc-viewport'>viewport</div>
    <div id="mc-column">
        <div id='mc-list' class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
            <div *ngFor="let l of list">
                <div id="mc-list-item">{{l}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mc-controls" class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
            <div class="control-placeholder" style="width: 150px">input box</div>
            <div class="control-placeholder" style="width: 75px">Fan</div>
            <div class="control-placeholder" style="width: 75px">NetNew</div>
            <div class="control-placeholder" style="width: 150px">download DXF</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my css:

```
#mc-container {
  background-color: #ccccff;
  margin: 5px;
  max-width: 780px;
  width: 90%;
}

#mc-column {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  min-width: 150px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  max-width: 600px;

  flex: 1 1 0;
}

#mc-viewport {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#mc-list {
  background-color: lightcyan;
  width: 100%;
}
#mc-list-item {
  min-width: 150px;
  outline:  whitesmoke solid 1px;

}

#mc-controls {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.control-placeholder {
  outline:  whitesmoke solid 1px;
  font-size: small;
}

#mc-header {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the width as a percentage instead of using in px

Answer (score 0):

Using the class col-xl usually snaps at a pretty big size.

Or play around with @media only screen and (max-width: 620px) or a min-width property.

I might have this backwards but like

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
.someclass{
    display:none;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
.someclass{
    display:block;
```

}
}

Comment: Yep- that works well! It took a little learning, but the @media allows one to snap to certain widths given device widths. Also allowed me to make a third super small width where I just take over the whole screen, which is very handy. Thanks!